# How to use awk to search for strings in a while read loop

Tags: awk

I would like to loop through file1, which has two columns. Each column has a string that I would like to use to search in a dataframe file (file2) with 18 columns. I'd like to select rows from file2 that have both strings from file1 in two different columns to create a new file.

file1 (tab separated file with about 150 rows, it has no header)

```
#region      motif
Exon         ATG
Exon         CTG
5' UTR       GCC
3' UTR       GGC
```

file2 (tab separated file with about 1.5 million rows - has a header)
There are 18 columns. Column 18 has the region information from file1, and column 15 has the motif information from file 1.

```
chr start   end period  copyNum consensusSize   perMatch    perIndel    score   A   C   G   T   entropy motif   sequence    ID  region
chr1    15798   15822   3   8.3 3   77  0   29  0   40  20  40  1.52    TGC TGCTCCTGCTCCTTCTGCTGCTGCT   chr1_15798_15822_TGC    Exon
chr9    140196426   140196441   3   5.3 3   84  0   25  0   31  62  6   1.2 GGC GGCGGCGGCTGCGGCG    chr9_140196426_140196441_GGC    5' UTR
chr1    19282560    19282579    3   6.7 3   76  0   26  5   40  25  30  1.77    CTG CTGCTGCTGCTCCAGCTGCT    chr1_19282560_19282579_CTG  Exon
chr8    131028679   131028694   3   5.3 3   100 0   32  0   62  37  0   0.95    GCC GCCGCCGCCGCCGCCG    chr8_131028679_131028694_GCC    5' UTR
```

The expected output is to include all columns from file2, but only rows that match file 1 on both strings. From the example, rows 3 and 4 from file2 should be in the output.

When I do it manually without going through the loop, it works fine. But once it's in the loop I get an empty output file. This is what I have tried so far:

```
while read REGION MOTIF; do
       awk '$18 == "'${REGION}'" && $15 == "'${MOTIF}'"' file2 >> output.txt
done < file1.txt

I get the following errors:
awk: cmd. line:1: ($18 == "Exon" && $15 == "CAG
awk: cmd. line:1:                          ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: ($18 == "5'" && $15 == "UTR
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ unterminated string
```

Also tried the following with no error but empty output file:

```
while read REGION MOTIF; do
       awk -v a="$REGION" -v b="$MOTIF" '($18 == a && $15 == b)' file2.txt >> output.txt
done < file1.txt
```

If I do a single line in the command line, it works. So it's something to do with how the region and motif variables are being passed into awk I believe. The ones that don't work manually are the 5' UTR and 3' UTR, since they have the single quote I guess.

```
awk '($18 == "Exon" && $15 == "CTG")' file2.txt > output.txt

or

awk -v a="Exon" -v b="CAG" '($18 == a && $15 == b)' file2.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: `file1 (tab separated file with` you have to set the field separator to tab

Comment: @KamilCuk - tried that and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk` that stores all value from 1st column in `region` array and 2nd column in `motif` array while going through `file1`. Later we print records from `file2` if `$18` is found in `region` array and `$15` is found in `motif` array:

```sh
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {region[$1]; motif[$2]; next}
$18 in region && $15 in motif' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```sh
chr1    15798   15822   3   8.3 3   77  0   29  0   40  20  40  1.52    CTG TGCTCCTGCTCCTTCTGCTGCTGCT   chr1_15798_15822_TGC    Exon
```

Comment: please provide a sample input from `file2` so that I can test and tweak if needed.

Comment: I edited the question to add a sample of file2, thanks for your help

Comment: In file2 you have `TGC` but in `file1` you have have `CTG` so there is a mismatch

Comment: It's still not working for me, so i have no idea what's happening. Maybe it has something to do with the formatting of my files...

Comment: Ok the issue was that I had to convert dos2unix for file1. Facepalm emoji! Thanks for this code though, it helped fix the issues with the single quotes in the UTR region names. Also works faster than the way I was trying it.